# When does a Rails query calls for an EXPLAIN query to PostGreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, explain

While updating all entries in my DB, between two of them I got the following query:

```
Product Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."vtex_identifier" = '158677' LIMIT 1
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 (0.4ms)  UPDATE "products" SET "provider_id" = 3, "updated_at" = '2014-02-19 15:14:32.404889' WHERE "products"."id" = 469
 (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Product Load (5.8ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."vtex_identifier" = '157683' LIMIT 1


EXPLAIN (0.5ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."vtex_identifier" = '157683' LIMIT 1
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."vtex_identifier" = '157683' LIMIT 1
                           QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=0.00..226.53 rows=1 width=267)
->  Seq Scan on products  (cost=0.00..226.53 rows=1 width=267)
     Filter: ((vtex_identifier)::text = '157683'::text)
(3 rows)


 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 (0.4ms)  UPDATE "products" SET "provider_id" = 3, "updated_at" = '2014-02-19 15:14:32.920676' WHERE "products"."id" = 470
 (0.5ms)  COMMIT
```

Does anybody know when and why it is called? Curiously, the text of other queries after this EXPLAIN command came all in **bold style**

Comment: What code produced that log, and that series of commands? Seems weird to me that Rails would ever use `EXPLAIN` but lots that ActiveRecord does is weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord automatically runs EXPLAIN query to detect slow running queries. `development` environments get the following configuration. For any query that takes more than 0.5 seconds, it automatically runs EXPLAIN query.

```
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

You can disable it by setting it to nil

```
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = nil
```

[Read](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-explain/)

Comment: Note: This was removed in Rails 4. You can no longer use this to have auto explains. This is the commit that removed this feature: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d3688e02ca52c0b72d3092e8498da51e06b7fc58